# Can you use "never" and "forever" together?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

So I was asked if you can use "never forever" as in "I will never give up forever."  I honestly never heard of it out side of lyrics and movie titles, but I haven't heard the wording is wrong neither.

Is it grammatically correct to use "never forever"?
If not, do they use it? How do you say it in the right grammar?

I frequently hear "I will never ever…," which would imply "I" won't forever…,  and I also want to know if it differs from "I will never forever…."

Comment: 'Never ever' is a set phrase synonymous with 'never' but adding emphasis. // "I will never give up drinking coffee forever" implies that I might however be considering temporary abstinence. Apart from all the lyric / film / book references, the rare examples of 'never forever' on the internet seem to reference different concepts. Thus "Royalties are never forever" [I'd use for ever here] means that << There are _never cases_ where _royalties on a recording say are payable for ever_ >>.

Comment: Reading your answer, I think I worded wrong.

Comment: So, "I will never give in forever." mean that (I may give in for now but) the time will come when I don't give in?

Comment: My friend mean "never in the lasting future" by "never forever", emphasizing "forever"

Comment: Never _is_ forever. "Never forever" is like "ATM machine".

Comment: If Kate Bush can get away with it, so can you.

Answer (score -1):

The sentence "I will never give up forever." is grammatically correct. *Giving up forever* means that the person won't ever try again. *Never* doing that means that the person will always try again.

The sense of the phrase *never give up forever* is that although the person might take a break from whatever they are attempting, they are stating that they will always return to try again.

If the intent was to apply *forever* to *never give up*, you need some punctuation between up and forever, such as

- ... will never give up. Forever.

This now has the sense that not only will the speaker try again, they won't even stop trying.

The second part of your question is:

> I frequently hear "I will never ever…," which would imply "I" won't forever…, and I also want to know if it differs from "I will never forever…."

*Will never ever* uses *ever* as an intensifier. It conveys the same idea as the plain *will never*, but does so more emphatically. The three phrases are quite different.

Consider the following. Alice and Bob are names often used in the field of data protection (encryption, cryptosystems, etc). Suppose Bob sent Alice a message in a state that allowed a third party to read its plain text.

1. Alice *will never (ever)* hold that against Bob.
2. Alice *won't* hold that against Bob *forever*.
3. Alice will *never* hold that against Bob *forever*.

The first says that Alice won't hold it against Bob today, tomorrow, or any time in the future, and that this stems from some aspect of Alice - if Bob did it again, Alice would not hold that against Bob, either.

The second says that Alice might hold it against Bob today, maybe even tomorrow, but at some time she will stop holding it against him. However, this is a one-off statement. It says nothing about how Alice would react if Bob did it again.

The third is similar to the second, with Bob in trouble for some finite period, but like the first, it carries the sense that something about Alice will eventually extend forgiveness to Bob each time.

Comment: -If the intent was to apply forever to never give up
・yes. Can you say "Forever I will never give up"?

Comment: That phrasing is a little awkward. If you're after emphasis, I prefer this version: *I won't ever give up*.

Comment: We are Japanese and the sentence is Japanese-centered (and it sounds like poem a little too). The sentence probably includes emphasis, but it needs to include continuance of not doing … too. (To me, "I won't give up. Forever." in Japanese seems a bit awkward, but whatever) If "I won't give up. Forever." isn't awkward in English, it best fits my friend's sentence'

Comment: In that case, you can just use "I will never give up".